# selecting distinct value order by desc

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to select distinct `customer_id` order by either `s.no` or `time` or anyhow

```
s.no     customer_id         time
1        3                   100001
2        2                   100002
3        4                   100003
4        3                   100004
5        2                   100005
```

i am using

```
select distinct(customer_id) from table_name order by time DESC
```

and it is giving the answer as `4  2  3` but as i want it should be `2  3  4`

Comment: It is a best practice to order by the fields in your SELECT.  If you want it to be `2 3 4` then `ORDER BY number`.  In your case, you are listing DISTINCT numbers.  How is supposed to know which time value to use for the sort?

Comment: Use `Order by number`

Comment: @AgRizzo I think he's trying to say that the first three records are selected (they have number 4,2,3) but he wants to select the last three (which have number 2,3,4)

Comment: number refers to someone `id` so its like `customer_id` so its `s.no` or `time` is important

Answer (score 16, accepted):

So your problem statement is "You want the list of customer_id, sorted in descended order from their largest time value", right?

```
SELECT customer_id, MAX(time)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY customer_id
ORDER BY MAX(time) DESC
```

Comment: This is the simplest solution that works! The other solutions suggested a Left Join and some very complex workarounds to support ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY

Answer (score 0):

You have to do a second select like this:

```
SELECT
    `number`
FROM
(
    SELECT
        DISTINCT(number) AS number
    FROM
        `table_name`
    ORDER BY
        `time` DESC
) AS `temp`
ORDER BY
    `number` ASC
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be done using second query

```
$query = "SELECT * 
            FROM (SELECT customer_id
                FROM table_name                 
                ORDER BY customer_id DESC) as rows              
            GROUP BY customer_id";
```